# How Netty Guarantees No Packet Loss

Tags: tcp, netty

The netty client establishes a TCP connection with the server, and the client sends data that must be received to the server, such as channel. `writeAndFlush()`. Under the normal bandwidth, do I need to do the guaranteed work in the application layer?

Answer (score 2):

TCP is pretty good at handling lost packets, so unless you need specific requirement you don't have to do anything in the application layer.

For a general overview on packet loss regarding TCP you can check this [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_loss)

Comment: TCP provides reliable data transmission. What I want to know is whether netty guarantees no packet loss from the application layer to the transport layer under normal conditions.Frequent data transmission leads to packet loss.Is it because the buffer of channel is too small?